# Add multiple items to a MVC Kendo grid without closing the popup

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using MVC Kendo grid to display a list of items. I can add items one by one fine using the Kendo default popup.

Now I would like to be able to add a lot of items in a short time. My idea is to add the first item and be able to keep the popup open to add a second item, and so on.

When I press 'Update' for the first item, I would like to insert this item and reset all the popup field with the default values ready to add a second one.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me. On the Grid RequestEnd event I call a JS method that will call the Click() method of my button.

/* Script */
function ItemRequestEnd(e) {
    switch (e.type)
    {
        
        case 'create':
              window.setTimeout(ReopenItemWin, 500);
        break;
        case 'update':
            ...
        break;
    }
    onDetailsRequestEnd(e);
}

function ReopenItemWin() {
        $('#createItem').click();
}

/* View */
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myModel>().Name("Grid_Item")
    ...
    .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("ItemRequestEnd"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. On the Grid RequestEnd event I call a JS method that will call the Click() method of my button.

```
/* Script / 
function ItemRequestEnd(e) { 
 switch (e.type) { 
  case 'create': 
   window.setTimeout(ReopenItemWin, 500); 
   break; 
  case 'update': 
   ... 
   break; 
  } 
 onDetailsRequestEnd(e); 
} 
function ReopenItemWin() { 
 $('#createItem').click(); } 

/ View */ 
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myModel>().Name("Grid_Item") 
  ... 
  .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("ItemRequestEnd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add objects in code like this:

```
        var grid = $("#" + gridname).data("kendoGrid");
        var c = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new YourClass() { Id = 0, ... }));
        grid.dataSource.insert(0, c);
```

And then iterate as many times needed.

Comment: your solution is not really adapted to my project. I do not know how many items the user will want to add. Thanks Peter for your help and time.